# Novu push notifications for Flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-pub, novu

Does somebody know is it possible to use "Novu" notification [Simple components and APIs for managing all communication channels in one place: Email, SMS, Direct, and Push](https://novu.co/) with Flutter? I'd like to connect  push notification to
my App with Novu in Flutter with package and get push notification. But I can't find any flutter package connected with Novu

I tried to find Novu package in the Flutter pub but I didn't.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the [Novu](https://novu.co/) only supports PHP, Vue, Angular, React, NextJS, NodeJS, VanillaJS, Kotlin, Ruby, .Net, Python, Go, and NestJS. Open the Quickstart panel at https://docs.novu.co/overview/introduction/ to view.